# What's the meaning of /e/, /i:/, /a:/, /z/ and /p/?

Tags: phonetics, ipa

> Write the words in the right column. Read them.
>
> pink, elephant, teacher, friend, jeans, class, programmer, green,
> animals, bed, are, zoos, desk, postman, cream, men, these, monkeys,
> dance, pet, read, shop, sharpener, girls, tree, car
>
> [columns:] /e/, /i:/, /a:/, /z/, /p/

[page image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZOgPk.jpg)

I was doing homework with the kid and I found this. Can anyone explain what this is about?

Comment: For example, if you know the pronunciation represented by symbol /z/ then you put in that column the words with that sound in them.  (I got 6 of them.)  And so on for the other columns.

Comment: I still fail to understand it. can you please give me some examples? Also, what does the : mean?

Comment: The symbols between the slashes are simplified [IPA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPA), that is, phonetic writing. The triangular colon (ː) indicates length, so /aː/ means ‘long a’. Strictly speaking, that sound doesn’t exist in English (except if you’re from Boston—it’s the ‘ah’ sound made when Bostonites say ‘car’), but here it’s clearly meant to represent the vowel /ɑː/, as in _are_ or /æː/ as in _dance_ (US English). Hard to know which, though—unless you’re in the UK, in which case both _are_ and _dance_ would belong in that category.

Comment: This seems like a badly designed exercise to me. As Janus says, "are" apparently is meant to be classified with the sound /a:/, which means that "sharpener" has two of the listed sounds: /a:/ and /p/. The words "jeans" and "these" contain both /i:/ and /z/, and so does "monkeys" for many people. What's on the rest of the page/the preceding page? Is there no more explanation?

Comment: It says /a:/, so I assume this workbook is from the UK, not the US.  As often happens, the homework helper does not understand it, because the kid didn't tell him what the lesson was about.

Comment: _These_ and _monkeys_ both contain /i:/ **and** /z/. Which column is the right column?

Comment: Get one of the Cambridge Encyclopedias by David Crystal (_Cambridge Encyclopedia of Language_ and _Cambridge Encyclopedia of the English Language_). They're both great and they both explain everything you or your kid need to learn about English. Don't be surprised you can't understand it -- they didn't teach it when you went to school.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The /i:/ etc. is [Phonetics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonetics).

The ':' usually indicates a 'Long' vowel, meaning its pronunciation is longer compared to a vowel without an ':'.

E.g. /i:/ vs. /i/, green vs. fit

Comment: The answer marked correct is incorrect. The English meaning of long and short vowels is: * a short = cat æ
* a long = name eɪ These are two totally different sounds phonetically and not indicated by a colon. The : in IPA is a **lengthening** of the preceding vowel. It represents the **same** sound but lengthened. So the example above should be: * E.g. /i:/ vs. /i/, fiit vs. fit (The colon is just making the vowel sound 'last' longer. Not making it 'long' as is often described for English vowels.) See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vowel_length

Comment: "Green" and "fit" have different vowels (not just differing in length) -  /ɡriːn/ versus /fɪt/.

Answer (score 0):

International Phonetic Alphabet (IPA)/Phonetic symbols- // /ː/ /ɑː/ // // etc.

// (short vowel)- bed/bd/, elephant/ˈl.ɪ.fənt/ or /ˈl.ə.fənt/, friend/frnd/,  desk/dsk/, men/mn/, pet /pt/, pen /pn/, beg/bɡ/, led/ld/, fell/fl/,

ː (length mark)

/ː/ is longer than /ɪ/ or  /ɪ/ is shorter than /ː/

lead/lːd/, lid/lɪd/, feel/fiːl/, fill/fɪl/, seat/siːt/, sit/sɪt/,  bead/biːd/, bid/bɪd/,

/ː/ - teacher/ˈtː.tʃər/, green/ɡrːn/,  cream/krːm/,these/ðːz/, read/rːd/, tree/trː/, zeal/zːl/

/ɪ/ - pink /pɪŋk/, pit/pɪt/

/ɑː/ (long vowel)- It is similar to 'Ah' (when a doctor looks into your mouth and asks you to say 'Ah')

class British/klɑːs/ (or American/klæs/), are/ɑːr/, car/kɑːr/, heart British/hɑːt/  American/hɑːrt/, park British/pɑːk/ American/pɑːrk/

// - pink/ɪŋk/, pet/et/, park British/ɑːk/ American/ɑːrk/, pit/ɪt/, pen /en/

// - jean /dʒiːn/, animal/ˈæn.ɪ.məl/, these/ðiː/,  girls/ɡɜːl/, eggs/eɡ/,   goods/ɡʊd/, zoo/uː/, plays/pleɪ/, zeal/iːl/, who's /huː/,